# Pivoting in SQL Combining two Columns

Tags: sql-server

This may explain better what I am trying to do if anyone can help.

This is the query.

```
select  sb.col_nm  + '.' + sb.col_r_nm as 'Combined', mt.vlu_cd, at.tmplt_id
from templ_t at
inner join aud_bat_t b on b.tmp_id = at.tmp_id 
inner join stats_dtl_t mt on mt.batch_id = b.batch_id
inner join lg_clmn_t sb on sb.lg_col_id = mt.lg_col_id
where at.tmplt_id = 6
order by sb.col_nm  + '.' + sb.col_r_nm, mt.vlu_cd, at.tmplt_id
```

So i have the first two rows comined and what the query retuns now is for example.

```
**Combined           vlu_cd      tmplt_id**
prc_crf.premium      4567          6
prc_crf.premium      8574          6
prc_crf.premium      4789          6
prc_crf.sales        7777          6
prc_crf.sales        5487          6
prc_crf.sales        8888          6
prc_crf.sales        9874          6
lrt_lr_premium       7755          6
lrt_lr_premium       4874          6
lrt_lr_premium       9999          6
ptr_pr_sales         5555          6
ptr_pr_sales         3333          6
ptr_pr_sales         6523          6
ptr_pr_sales         1489          6
```

So what i want is when i pivot the data is to just show the following where all  the rows in the Column called Combined become Columns with the vlu_cd for each listed under in rows.

Can anyone help with a query to Pivot this data where it Pivots all the new columns instead of having to manually type them in.

Sorry if this is confusing I am a beginner so, if i am not clear if you ask i can try explain it better.

So from the results above if i could Pivot the data like this where i don't have to manually type in each row when Pivoting.

```
prc_crf.premium   prc_crf.sales   lrt_lr_premium   ptr_pr_sales
4567                7777                7755            3333        
8574                5487                4874            6523
4789                8888                9999            1489
                    9874                5555
```

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: Have you looked into PIVOT? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN stored_col_b.col_nm = 'jobs_t' AND stored_col_b.col_r_nm = 'job_id' THEN value_col_b.vlu_cd ELSE 0 END) AS [jobs_t.job_id]
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN stored_col_b.col_nm = 'road_t' AND stored_col_b.col_r_nm = 'road_id' THEN value_col_b.vlu_cd ELSE 0 END) AS [road_t.road_id]
FROM stored_col_b
     INNER JOIN value_col_b
         ON value_col_b.col_id = stored_col_b.col_id
```

Add more columns when needed

Comment: Is there anyway i can Pivot the data without manually typing in each of the rows to combine individually. At the moment I have only two but as i go on this will be hundreds, so doing this manually would be very time consuming.

Comment: @B.H, I would copy the values to excel and use a formula like `=",SUM(CASE WHEN stored_col_b.col_nm = '" & A1 & "' AND stored_col_b.col_r_nm = '" & B1 & "' THEN value_col_b.vlu_cd ELSE 0 END) AS [" & A1 & "." & B1 & "]"` but I don't understand how you are supposed to use a query with hundreds of columns.

Comment: Thank you for the reply I have edited my main question up the top this might explain things better.

Comment: @B.H, I have never worked with a product which accepts a variable number of columns as a result from a query so I can't help you further.

Answer (score 1):

This is a a small sp I use to pivot data

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[prc-Pivot] (@Select varchar(1000),
    @PvotCol varchar(100),
    @Summaries varchar(100),
    @GroupBy varchar(100),
    @OtherCols varchar(100) = Null)
AS

Set NoCount On
Set Ansi_Warnings Off

Declare @Vals varchar(max);
Set @Vals = ''
Set @OtherCols= IsNull(', ' + @OtherCols,'')
Create Table #Temp  (Pvot varchar(100))
Insert Into #temp
Exec ('Select Distinct Convert(varchar(100),' + @PvotCol + ') as Pvot FROM (' + @Select + ') A')
Select @Vals = @Vals + ', ' + Replace(Replace(@Summaries,'(','(CASE WHEN ' + @PvotCol + '=''' + Pvot +  ''' THEN '),')[', ' END) As [' + Pvot ) From #Temp Order by Pvot
Drop Table #Temp
Exec ('Select ' + @GroupBy + @OtherCols + @Vals + ' From (' + @Select + ') A Group By ' + @GroupBy + ' Order by 1,2')
Set NoCount Off
Set Ansi_Warnings on
```

Feel free to play with options:

```
Exec [prc-Pivot] 'Select grpby=1,colstr=col_nm+''.''+col_r_nm,vlu_cd from aaa','colstr','sum(vlu_cd)[]','grpby'
```

Retrurns

```
grpby   jobs_t.job_id   road_t.road_id
1       789             468
```